# Deep learning using Keras: How to understand the Lambda layer and lambda function?

Tags: lambda, keras

My code is like this:

```
labels = Input(name='the_labels', shape=[1], dtype='float32')
input_length = Input(name='input_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')
label_length = Input(name='label_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')

loss_out = Lambda(ctc_lambda_func, output_shape=(1,), name="ctc")([output, labels, input_length, label_length])

model = Model(input=[net_input, labels, input_length, label_length],  output=[loss_out])
model.compile(loss={'ctc': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred},  optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[])
```

And my ctc_lambda_func definition is as follows:

```
def ctc_lambda_func(args):
  y_pred, labels, input_length, label_length = args
  # the 2 is critical here since the first couple outputs of the RNN
  # tend to be garbage:
  shift = 2
  y_pred = y_pred[:, shift:, :]
  input_length -= shift
 return K.ctc_batch_cost(labels, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
```

I can't understand:

1. loss_out = Lambda(ctc_lambda_func, output_shape=(1,),
   name="ctc")([output, labels, input_length, label_length])

Somebody said that a Lambda is a layer, but how do I have to use this layer?

And `(ctc_lambda_func, output_shape=(1,), name="ctc")` are parameters of function "Lambda" – but what are the parameters `([output, labels, input_length, label_length])`?

2. `loss={'ctc': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred}` is the loss function. I found that the loss function list as follows, but without the ctc.

   - mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred) mean_absolute_error(y_true,
     y_pred)
   - mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred)
   - mean_squared_logarithmic_error(y_true, y_pred)
   - squared_hinge(y_true,y_pred)
   - hinge(y_true, y_pred)
   - categorical_hinge(y_true, y_pred)
   - logcosh(y_true, y_pred)
   - categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
   - sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
   - binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
   - kullback_leibler_divergence(y_true, y_pred)
   - poisson(y_true,  y_pred)
     -cosine_proximity(y_true, y_pred)

I am new in Keras and Python. I appreciated very much if you can give me some explanation.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a look into this in order to improve your questions (especially formatting and proof reading): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It will make it much easier for others to understand and help you.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a correct usage of Keras library. The code seems to circumvent an API [shortcoming](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2121).

1. The Lambda layer is normally used to implement a custom function as part of the computation graph within Keras. `([output, labels, input_length, label_length])` are the tensors passed to the custom function, in this the loss function. The reason behind this convoluted solution is the API doesn't only allows `(output, labels)` signature for loss functions.
2. Now that the loss function is implemented, the second part of the code bypasses the Keras built-in loss functions by returning the prediction tensor `y_pred` as is. The `loss={'ctc':...` is bypassed loss for the `'ctc'` layer, ie Lambda.

You can implement custom loss functions but that is not the intended usage of the API. For a solution with loss that has multiple parameters have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50295689/correct-way-of-loss-function).